# Stacked Bar Chart with Line Chart not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, charts, jqplot

I need to create a bar stacked combination chart with line

See example:

```
    multiAxisModel = new LineChartModel();
    multiAxisModel.setStacked(true);
    BarChartSeries boys = new BarChartSeries();
    boys.setLabel("Boys");

    boys.set("2004", 120);
    boys.set("2005", 100);
    boys.set("2006", 44);

    BarChartSeries boys1 = new BarChartSeries();
    boys1.setLabel("boys1");

    boys1.set("2004", 20);
    boys1.set("2005", 10);
    boys1.set("2006", 44);

    LineChartSeries girls = new LineChartSeries();
    girls.setLabel("Girls");
    girls.setXaxis(AxisType.X2);
    girls.setYaxis(AxisType.Y2);  
    girls.set("A", 52);
    girls.set("B", 60);
    girls.set("C", 110);

    multiAxisModel.addSeries(boys);
    multiAxisModel.addSeries(boys1);
    multiAxisModel.addSeries(girls);

    multiAxisModel.setTitle("Multi Axis Chart");
    multiAxisModel.setMouseoverHighlight(false);
    multiAxisModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, new CategoryAxis("Years"));
    multiAxisModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X2, new CategoryAxis("Period"));

    Axis yAxis = multiAxisModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Birth");
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(200);
    Axis y2Axis = new LinearAxis("Number");
    y2Axis.setMin(0);
    y2Axis.setMax(200);         
    multiAxisModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.Y2, y2Axis);
```

I try few options but the line diagram is not overlapping on the line according to the Y Axis.

This is working only with multiAxisModel.setStacked(false);

Any idea why ?

Thanks